# Prevent Cron jobs from Single Point of Failure

Tags: server, cron, distributed-computing, job-scheduling

I have many cron jobs running on server, which include like DB Backup (daily), sending Notification to users(hourly).

Currently i have 5 API Servers, and cron jobs is setup on one of the API Server.

I want to prevent Cron jobs from Single Point of failure. What if the machine crashed in which cron jobs has been setup.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: I'd say this isn't so much a cron question as a server high availability question. I did a quick search and found this thread:

https://serverfault.com/questions/227659/how-to-make-cronjobs-high-available

Comment: Thanks for replying... I will check this thread.